# EMS Web application is not allowing login

Tags: ems

I've installed EMS Desktop client, platform API and EMS web application in a VM. EMS desktop client is working as expected. I can login using my user name and password. But when I trying to access the web app using http://localhost/EmsWebApp/ it is showing a home page as the image attached. [image] Showing welcome guest, there is no option to logout the current gust user or not showing any features of the application. I would like to know how to create a new user and login with that credentials into the web app.